# Hyperplanes without Axiom of Choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice, projective-geometry, projective-space

For any projective space that contains more than one point, is it possible to prove that it contains a hyperplane without using the Axiom of Choice?

It's easy enough to prove that there exists a projective space that would be  isomorphic to a hyperplane if the hyperplane existed. The lines and planes (seen as points and lines respectively) passing through a specific point in the parent space do the job.

Comment: Where does the axiom of choice get in?

Comment: Well, if the dimension is finite, there is no need f Axiom of Choice.